# Why is the Newton quotient measurable when the conditions are like the following.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x, y), 0 \le x, y, \le 1$, satisfy the following conditions:

- for each $x$, $f(x, y)$ is an integrable function of $y$.
- $\displaystyle\frac{\partial{}f(x, y)}{\partial{}x}$ is a bounded function of $(x, y)$.

Then show that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial{}f(x, y)}{\partial{}x}$ is a measurable unction of $y$ for each $x$.

---

I think the first condition is $$\int_{[0, 1]\times[0, 1]} f(x, y) ~ dy \quad \text{ exists and finite.}$$

Moreover, the second condition is, for a constant $M\in\mathbb{R}^1$, $$\left|\frac{\partial{}f(x, y)}{\partial{}x}\right|\le{}M$$

My changing of conditions are correct?

And $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h.
$$ is why measurable?

Comment: I cannot answer the second question but you correctly wrote the conditions (you should add "for all $x$" and "for all $x,y$" of the right domain, though).

Comment: @anderstood Thank you.

Comment: [page 27, Solution 5](http://math.rice.edu/~idu/Sp05/AnalysisV11.pdf#page=27)

Comment: In your page, $F_n$ is a measurable function by application of (i) why?

Comment: [A bounded function on a set of finite measure is Lebesgue integrable if  and only if it is measurable - page 114, Theorem 7](http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/books/royden-fitzpatrick/royden-fitzpatrick.pdf#page=114). Please, use "@"+nick if you want to address somebody in comments, because otherwise I will not get a notification.

Comment: @hcl14 Thank you very much.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Sorry, don't mind my previous deleted comments. They have fixed $x$, everything is ok.